# How to make Spring Boot application accessible by external IP address of the server?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm a newbie to Spring Boot. I have a REST API application written in Spring Boot. When I execute my Spring Boot JAR, everything is okay and I can access the REST API with the `localhost` address instead of the actual one:

```
http://localhost:8083/articles
```

But when I try to access the REST API by my external IP address, I can't do it:

```
http://100.90.80.70:8083/articles
```

`netstat -antu` command in the Linux terminal gives me the following output:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address  Foreign Address  State
tcp6       0      0      :::8083            :::*        LISTEN
```

As I understand, my app is accessible only in `localhost`, because it hasn't a `foreign address`.

My `application.properties` file has only this line:

```
server.port=8083
```

Also, when I try to add a `server.address` line to `application.properties` like that:

```
server.address=100.90.80.70
server.port=8083
```

I have the following `Exception`: `Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address`.

So my question is: how to make Spring Boot application accessible by external IP address of the server? Thank you.

Comment: i think you need to enable Cross Origin Requests in your application, here is the link for it https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Are you behind a firewall which might be blocking port 8083? Or behind a router which does not forward request to port 8083 on your ip to your computer?

Comment: @pramesh, I have added my IP address to the origins list like that: `@CrossOrigin(origins = ["http://100.90.80.70:8083"])` and added a `WebMvcConfigurer` bean to `App.class`, but no success.

Comment: @Mark, thank you, I'm checking it.

Comment: What do you mean by *external ip-address*. Is this the address of your own system or the actual remote external ip-address?

Comment: @M. Deinum, I try to execute REST API app on _my system_ and access it on other systems with REST requests. So other systems have to use my external IP address to access my app.

Comment: Again define what you mean with external IP address. You still haven't explained that. Is that the IP address of your machine or the IP address you have on the outside through your router/internet provider/ .... I know what you are trying to achieve, however your notion of **external IP address** is important here. If it is not the IP address of your local machine you will need to do some forwarding on your router for incoming requests to your machine, or open up a port (as it might be closed, etc.).

Comment: @M. Deinum, it's the IP address of my machine.

Comment: Then check the error message why you cannot bind to the external IP address.The default is to bind to all addresses so without specifying the `server.address` it should bind to all available IP address.

Comment: @Mark, thank you so much, man, it really was because of firewall! After I opened `8083` port in firewall settings, all works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mark said, the problem is in the firewall. I have opened `8083` port in the firewall settings and now I can access my REST API app by the external IP address:

```
http://100.90.80.70:8083/articles
```

Linux command to check firewall status:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Open `8083` port for remote access by TCP protocol:

```
sudo ufw allow 8083/tcp
```

More settings here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-open-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-linux-12-04-14-04-lts/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same by configuring port forwarding on my router, to allow traffic from public ip

Answer (score 0):

In my OpenStack environment, after much debugging, the solution was to create a new Security Group Rule, which looks like this:
[Security Group Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szTb4.png).

Note that my Spring Boot application was deployed on port 8080.
I also noticed that on ubuntu18 the firewall is disabled by default. It did not cause any problems.